# IOS unable to insert data in to mysql database

Tags: ios

Hello everyone I am trying to insert my user data in myaql database using JSON. But i am unable to do so, data is not inserting and getting no error. following is my code.

### Objective C Code

```
    {
     NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&password=  %@&phone=%@",self.name.text, self.Pass.text,self.phone.text,self.email.text];
     NSData *data = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my url"];
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [request setHTTPBody:data];
     NSURLResponse *response;
     NSError *err;
     NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
    }
```

I am using this code to insert textfields data into my mysql database.It seems no error but data is not inserting in my database. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: there is a space after password= ?? and what print NSLog?

Comment: NSLog print response data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your iOS implementation is correct, but your server side is not. 
You could try the following:
In your Server-side script, where your MySQL insert-statement is being generated, just do a

```
echo $insertScript;
```

and then run your App again and see what the response says. It should return a valid MySQL insert script. Copy it and run it on your server's mysql instance and see what happens

Also, remove those spaces in your password field

Answer (score 3):

Your first line itself doesn't seem true:

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&password=  %@&phone=%@",

self.name.text, self.Pass.text,self.phone.text,self.email.text];
```

1. Do you require space " " after text "password="
2. In formation the sequence is: name, email, password, phone, but in parameter list phone is at third place and email at last.

It should be:

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&password=%@&phone=%@",

self.name.text, self.email.text,self.Pass.text,self.phone.text];
```

**I guess that's causing issue, it might be in datatype mismatch with database table schema, for phone column (numbers) to email column (characters).**